# Count and Sort row showing count number

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

I have a table with structure: id (primary key), name, ep

I want to sort the elements order by id, where name = test, showing the count number of the row..

example:

```
id - name - ep - count
930 - test - 1 - 1
931 - test - 2 - 2
932 - test - 3 - 3
933 - test - 4 - 4
934 - test - 7 - 5
935 - test - 9 - 6
```

I have tried:

```
select name, id, count(*) as count from episodios where name = "test" group by id order by count asc;
```

But i'm getting error on mysql.. #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Could someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: 8.0.3, in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

mysql 8 has window function `ROW_NUMBER`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tmptable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `ep` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tmptable
>   (`id`, `name`, `ep`)
> VALUES
>   ('930', 'test', '1'),
>   ('931', 'test', '2'),
>   ('932', 'test', '3'),
>   ('933', 'test', '4'),
>   ('934', 'test', '7'),
>   ('935', 'test', '9');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `id`, `name`, `ep`,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `name` ORDER BY `ep`) as cnt
> FROM
> tmptable
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name | ep | cnt
> --: | :--- | -: | --:
> 930 | test |  1 |   1
> 931 | test |  2 |   2
> 932 | test |  3 |   3
> 933 | test |  4 |   4
> 934 | test |  7 |   5
> 935 | test |  9 |   6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c421a5cf62c2108bd6a93aebd0f0b58c)*

MySQL 5 has this option, as you have problems with the window function, i would recommend updating if possible

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tmptable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `ep` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tmptable
>   (`id`, `name`, `ep`)
> VALUES
>   ('930', 'test', '1'),
>   ('931', 'test', '2'),
>   ('932', 'test', '3'),
>   ('933', 'test', '4'),
>   ('934', 'test', '7'),
>   ('935', 'test', '9');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `id`, `name`, `ep`,
> IF(@name = name, @rn :=  @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as cnt
> ,@name := `name`
> FROM
> tmptable, (SELECT @rn := 0, @name := '') t1
> ORDER BY `name`, `ep`
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name | ep | cnt | @name := `name`
> --: | :--- | -: | --: | :--------------
> 930 | test |  1 |   1 | test           
> 931 | test |  2 |   2 | test           
> 932 | test |  3 |   3 | test           
> 933 | test |  4 |   4 | test           
> 934 | test |  7 |   5 | test           
> 935 | test |  9 |   6 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6d3c4b6c86fd48d3ac16701b45c9beec)*

Comment: Thanks! Was exaclty what i wanted.. i got only some error/warning in phpmyadmin when went to execute this query, something about alias.. but it worked.

Comment: Try to update, or use the mysql6  version in the meantime, if not possible, the order of the columns must stay, because of the logic

Comment: @kanohn . . . The code uses variables for older versions of MySQL is not correct.  MySQL specifically warns that variables (such as `@name` in this example) should not be referenced in one expression and assigned in  another, because the order of evaluation of `SELECT` expressions is not guaranteed.  Use `row_number()`.

Comment: @gordonlinoff I got the expression warning/error on row_number() code, and i'm using Mysql 8, the other code with name i don't got errors, however both codes worked fine, just the first i got the warning, no idea why.

Comment: @kanohn . . . I'm just warning you that the variables are not guaranteed to "work fine" and may stop working at some point. Use `row_number()` -- if you have MySQL 8+ it should work.